# 50% transparency in popup with javascript and/or center content

Tags: javascript, popup

I have this code to open a popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openwindow () {
   var win = window.open("http://www.google.com", "window1", "width=600,height=400,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
   win.focus();
   setTimeout(function () { win.close();}, 5000);
}
</script>
```

is there any way that the popup is displayed with a transparency of 50%?

since it is not possible transparency. Another question .. It can center the content of the popup .. to display 100px below and 70px to the right as show in the popup?
Sorry for my horrible English .. use google translator

Answer (score 0):

As it was documented in [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) you can't, at least using window.open()

If you want transparent popups, you may use an iframe embed and give transparency to that iframe, but in this method, the iframe should be in the parent window itself. In more detail, you may open a window that stores a transparent iframe, if that may help what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I can not use iframes. The page I want to open in popup have iframe-breaker ..

Answer (score 0):

No. A conventional popup initialized with `window.open` is a new browser window and all transparency settings are according your OS settings. Perhaps you choose another approach like http://drublic.github.io/css-modal/# or http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ There you have the power of setting the CSS styles as needed.

Comment: The page I want to open in the popup is not mine. It was to show some examples of other websites. But I see that I have no choice to create the examples myself and put them in an iframe.Thanks for the help

Answer (score -2):

Your won't have permission to access the DOM of the open window, so you cannot do this directly.

**Example of Permission Denied**

```
function openwindow () { 
var win = window.open("http://www.google.com", "window1", "width=600,height=400,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes"); win.focus();
//Permission denied 
win.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = 0.5; 

setTimeout(function () { win.close();}, 5000);
}

openwindow();
```